# Compute binary line thickness in normal direction

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, edge-detection

I would like to kindly ask you for the help with the definition of the line thickness. I have the binary curve. I need to find out a distance of each point of the curve skeleton to line edge in the direction of the normal. So, I firstly computed skeleton of the binary curve. Consequently, for each pixel of the skeleton I computed normal. This situation is depicted on the figure, showing the skeleton and a map of normal vectors from each pixel. In this point, I do not know how to compute the distance for each skeleton pixel to curve edge in the normal direction. Practically, I need to count number of the pixels (logical 1) from the skeleton pixels to the line edge in the normal direction. It means I need to obtain the vector, containing distance for each skeleton point. I would like to thank you in advance for your help.

Code for generating skeleton with normals:

```
clc;clear all;close all
i=rgb2gray(imread('Bin_Lines.bmp'));

BW=bwskel(logical(i));

% BW = image sceleton

Orientations = skeletonOrientation(BW,5); %5x5 box
Onormal = Orientations+90; %easier to view normals
Onr = sind(Onormal); %vv
Onc = cosd(Onormal); %uu
[r,c] = find(BW);    %row/cols
idx = find(BW);      %Linear indices into Onr/Onc

figure()
imshow(BW,[]);
%Plotting normals of binary skeleton
hold on
quiver(c,r,-Onc(idx),Onr(idx));
```

Here is the link where I store source codes and binary line image:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/j84ep3k1604hsza/AABm92TUBX6yIp29Gc0v_PHHa?dl=0

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use [distance transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform) to compute the distance of each interior pixel to the boundary. Matlab has [`bwdist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html) to do that for you.
Then you can extract the information for the skeleton pixels.

```
img = rgb2gray(imread('Bin_Lines.bmp'));  
bw = bwskel(img > 128);
dst = bwdist(img <= 128);  % need opposite contrast
distance_of_skel_pixels_to_boundary = dst(bw)
```

The distance `dst` looks like:
 [image]